# Adding values to an Array in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have a document stored in a collection in a mongo database. I want to be able to add to two arrays that are already in the document.

Method for creating the document and arrays:

```
public void addNewListName(String listName) {

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("lists");

    ArrayList< DBObject > array = new ArrayList< DBObject >();
    Document list = new Document ("name", listName)
            .append("terms", array)
            .append("definitions", array);
    collection.insertOne(list);
}
```

Method where I want to add values into the array:

```
public void addVocabToList(String listName, String newVocabTerm, String newDefinition) {

}
```

[image: The picture shows what the document looks like in MongoDB Compass after the first method is executed]

The picture shows what the document looks like in MongoDB Compass after the first method is executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addVocabToList()` implementation will look something like this:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("lists");

Document updatedDocument = collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    Filters.eq("name", listName),
    new Document("$push",
        new BasicDBObject("terms", new BsonString(newVocabTerm))
            .append("definitions", new BsonString(newDefinition))),
        new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER));
```

That code will:

- Find the document having name=`listName`
- Append the value of `newVocabTerm` to the `terms` array
- Append the the value of `newDefinition` to the `definitions` array
- Return the updated document (this part is optional)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you so much!