# How do i add another value to an array in an existing MongoDB document using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my current code

```
Document bitcoin = new Document("Currency", "Bitcoin").append("Values", Arrays.asList());
//bitCoinCollection.insertOne(bitcoin);

for(int i = 0; i<100;i++){
    BasicDBObject setNewFieldQuery = new BasicDBObject()
                    .append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("value", 100));
    mongoClient.getDatabase("Binance").getCollection("Binance")
               .updateOne(new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "tjena"), setNewFieldQuery);
}
```

It doesnt add any values to the excisting arraylist... is there a way to add it to an excisting arraylist  in a document? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding values to an Array in MongoDB with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597271/adding-values-to-an-array-in-mongodb-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

For this sample collection of one document with an array field using [MongoDB Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/):

```
{ _id: 1, fruits: [ "orange", "banana" ] }
```

The following Java code adds *one* new element to the `fruits` array:

```
Bson update = push("fruits", "guava");
Bson filter = eq("_id", new Integer(1));
UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(filter, update);
```

To add *multiple* elements all at once from a `List` collection:

```
Bson update = pushEach("fruits", Arrays.asList("grape", "apple", "peach"));
Bson filter = eq("_id", new Integer(1));
UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(filter, update);
```